# Unable to upload smart contract in Polkadot.js - contracts.instantiateWithCode: ready the whole time

Tags: smartcontracts, rust-cargo, polkadot-js, rust-ink

When I try to upload smart contract to Polkadot (local and testnet), this will popup after submitting [contracts.instantiateWithCode: ready](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVYv6.png) and it will be look like that the whole time and will not proceed following with this error:

`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON     --> starting at object with constructor 'r'     |     property '_events' -> object with constructor 's'     |     property 'ready' -> object with constructor 'i'     --- property 'context' closes the circle     at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)     at comm.12610700b267d6ed.js:4084:4637     at modu.3c11ec8a3f14b682.js:1:106879     at modu.31b08e9761e0e942.js:50:491708`

The smart contract is working on Substrate Contact UI but not in Polkadot.JS

I don't where this error is coming from.